# 'kubectl get pods' command fails on Windows, works on WSL2

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

The kubernetes documentation [includes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/list-all-running-container-images/#list-container-images-by-pod) an example command for listing container images by pod:

> **List Container images by Pod**
>
> The formatting can be controlled further by using the range operation to iterate over elements individually.
>
> ```
> kubectl get pods --all-namespaces -o=jsonpath='{range .items[*]}{"\n"}{.metadata.name}{":\t"}{range .spec.containers[*]}{.image}{", "}{end}{end}' |\
> sort
> ```

When I run this command in my Debian WSL2 instance, it correctly lists the containers for each pod I have running across all namespaces.

When I run the same command in the Windows commandline, I get an error: `error: a resource cannot be retrieved by name across all namespaces`:

```
C:\workspace>kubectl get pods --all-namespaces -o=jsonpath='{range .items[*]}{"\n"}{.metadata.name}{":\t"}{range .spec.containers[*]}{.image}{", "}{end}{end}' | sort
error: a resource cannot be retrieved by name across all namespaces
```

Is this a bug with kubectl, or is this command *nix only? Is there an OS-independent command for getting container images by pod across all namespaces?

(I'm running Debian on WSL2, Windows 10 Enterprise. Docker Desktop using WSL2 integration, K8S with minikube.)

Comment: does `kubectl get pods --all-namespaces` it works?

Comment: Yes. I think it's something specific to the `jsonpath`; if I specify a namespace with `-n <namespace>`, it gives an error: `error parsing jsonpath '{range, unclosed action`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From k8s offical [doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/jsonpath/):

> On Windows, you must double quote any JSONPath template that contains spaces (not single quote as shown above for bash). This in turn means that you must use a single quote or escaped double quote around any literals in the template. For example: `kubectl get pods -o=jsonpath="{range .items[*]}{.metadata.name}{'\t'}{.status.startTime}{'\n'}{end}"`

I think this will solve your problem.